Could We Tackle a DIY Bathroom Renovation to Fix Previous Owner’s Quick Fixes?
My husband and I are considering tackling a DIY small bathroom renovation, but we’re looking for advice on whether this is realistic for us as novice DIYers (though we are usually pretty handy with guidance from my dad/youtube videos ).
Here’s the situation: The previous owners of our home took a lot of shortcuts in the bathroom, and now it’s starting to show. The walls and shower tiles were originally retro yellow but were painted/expoxyed(?) over using a Rust-Oleum kit. The ceramic floor tiles were also painted and epoxied over, then covered with peel-and-stick tiles that seem to have been glued down with some kind of adhesive.
Our plan would involve removing all of the layers, assessing the damage, and starting fresh using proper techniques and materials. However, we’ve never done anything this extensive before, and we’re a little intimidated.
In the past, my dad has helped us with big projects like this as he has the experience and the tools, but he was recently diagnosed with MS and can no longer physically assist. We know he’d want to offer advice, but we’re worried that if we involve him too much, he’ll push himself too hard to help. Additionally, while don’t get us wrong he does GREAT WORK, he is very stubborn when it comes to demanding we get the best of the best supplies/materials, which wouldn’t be a problem if this wasn’t our starter home.
Have any of you taken on a similar project with limited experience? Do you think it’s realistic to attempt this ourselves with research and patience? Any tips, resources, or things we should be aware of before diving in?

Is it "just" redoing tiles on wall and floor, painting, etc.? Or is also real plumbing work? If it involves real plumbing it might be worthwhile to do prep yourself, then the plumber does the rough-in, then you put in floor, vanity, etc. then plumber connects new sink, etc. That keeps the stuff you do out of the "if we do it wrong the house floods" territory.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact thanks for raising that point! We do plan on replacing the original built-in two sink vanity and due to the looks of it, we will most likely need a plumber to help reconfigure the plumbing with a  new vanity

The toughest job with tiles is removing the old one, after that it is a DIY

If this is your only bathroom, consider how it’s going to impact your life if it’s out of service for an extended period. Beyond that, if you diy, go talk to the folks at the permit desk of your authority having jurisdiction. They’ll talk you through requirements and timing of inspections. Have an understanding beforehand of the size of drain pipes and electrical circuits serving the room.

Mr. Defenestrate makes a very good point. The bathroom will be unusable during most of this process. And if this is your first bath remodel, it'll probably take longer than you think.

We really can't determine for you what you are capable of doing. Additionally this question will be closed for asking for an opinion...so so helpful advice:
Bathrooms are one of the most complicated rooms to remodel.  Knowledge of all aspects of home repair and remodeling is needed.  Use the knowledge of your father over any info found on Youtube. (There is wrong advice there as well as good advice.)
If possible consider leaving the existing flooring and install LVP or LVT over it. (Save time and money on demo and LVP will only add about 3/16" )
Spend money on the shower.  That should be a complete tear out. Use cement board for wall sheathing. Cover that with a waterproofing like Redguard or an equivalent. Replace the controls rather than leave the old unit that could leak. Spend time on learning tiling techniques for showers. (How you install the tile is more important than what tile you are using.)
Finally, Don't be afraid to ask questions. Most of the people at tile and home stores are happy to give advice and guidance on what you need.

LVP is, I believe, "luxury vinyl plank flooring". Ideally resembles hardwood flooring, optically, thicker and more durable than simple vinyl flooring.

By the way, I would not recommend PVC flooring for a young family possibly planning to have children. The softeners are "endocrine disruptors", i.e. they mess with the hormones. That is particularly harmful during pregnancy and child development, among others affecting the sexual development. Floors have a large surface area and outgas a lot.

@Peter, I have never heard your claim regarding PVC flooring. What is your source?

You mean the endocrine disruption? I linked to a source! From the article's introduction: "Phthalates are a series of chemical substances, which are mainly used as plasticizers added to polyvinyl chloride", "negative long-term impacts on the success of pregnancy, child growth and development, and reproductive systems in both young children and adolescents". Hormone-like substances like phthalates interfere with sexual development. There is a growing suspicion that the increasing frequency of -- can I say atypical? -- sexual development among young people is related to such substances.

Sure, this article states "It’s premature to call it a theory; at this point, it barely qualifies as a hypothesis: some observers are putting forth the proposition that prenatal EDC exposures may affect gender identity—how a person identifies him- or herself, regardless of physical characteristics." But if I had a choice I'd try to minimize exposure to my baby.

@Peter,  Your comment are "The sky is falling" statement.  By your own admission any serious knowledge is unfounded.  There are so many theories about what is good and bad , it is irresponsible to post something that has no real scientific conclusion.  This is certainly not like what is known about asbestos or mold .    Further the manufacturing of VLP and LVT flooring does not, certainly maintain a definite use of the chemicals mentioned in the article and there is no support that the product actually "off gasses" anything harmful.

I didn't read past the abstract of the first link because I got to the "chronic exposure" part. Everybody should make their own choices, but I don't know how a floor that offgasses over a finite period could qualify as "chronic".
